# How to make a horizontal line in one side beside text with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I'm trying to create an horizontal line on the right side of a text.
I made it but the line disappears when I shorten the screen.

Here is my code:

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <h2 style="font-weight: bold">
            Services
          </h2>
          <hr style="flex-grow: 1; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make a line like the image below:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Given code doesn't reproduce the image. Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Add this responsive meta tag in `<head>` `</head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

---

Use `border` property to get desired output!

[***Codepen***](https://codepen.io/cursorrux/pen/jOBPMrY)

```css
body {
  padding: 0 12%;
}
.hr-line {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-top: 39px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div style="display: flex;">
                    <h2 style="font-weight: bold">Services</h2><hr class="hr-line">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is disappearing when I shorten the screen.

Comment: I'd edited the code, check now. I've attached codepen example.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is. I tested in Chrome and Edge browsers (Current version). Everything was fine. But when the screen is shortened, the line disappears.

Thank you so much for you effort.

Comment: I tested code on Chrome, it's appearing for minimum width `148` which is pretty ok for mobile screen. May be the problem is in responsiveness of page. Add mentioned meta tag in your `<head>` `</head>`.